# Error installing Rubygems on ruby command prompt in Win7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, devkit

I got the below error when trying to install rubygems on Ruby command prompt in Win7 (32bit). 
Note that I installed Ruby1.9.3 & added devkit (DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) to Ruby already.

Below are all things that I have tried:

```
 C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb init

 [INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193

 Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
 'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
 of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

 C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install

 [INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
 [INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

 C:\rubygems-1.8.24>ruby setup.rb install

 C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:53:in `sysconfdir': code converte
 r not found (UTF-16LE to Windows-1258) (Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError)
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:53:in `<class:Config
 File>'
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:30:in `<top (require
 d)>'
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from C:/rubygems-1.8.24/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from setup.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this issue by myself by selecting "English (United States)" in the dropdown list instead of "Vietnam" as previously in the dropdown list in "Advanced" tab of "Regional and Language Options" window, then the problem has been fixed.