# Vagrant failed on all commands with a same error "code converter not found"

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I installed vagrant 1.3.4 on my Windows 7 laptop then tried to type vagrant init from command line.  It failed with below error.  I tried other commands (even vagrant --help) but still receive a same error.  I tried googling for a while to no avail.  Is there anyone who can shed light on why this error happens?  Any input is appreciated.  Thanks

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:268:in `[]': code converter not found (
UTF-16LE to Windows-1258) (Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError)
    from    C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:268:in `block in _all'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:267:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:267:in `_all'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin//../embedded/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, this seems to be an issue with Ruby and I found the answer from this here:

[Error installing Rubygems on ruby command prompt in Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570226/error-installing-rubygems-on-ruby-command-prompt-in-win7)

I did the same, changing my locale from Vietnam to US and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `chcp 65001 > nul` at the top of `vagrant.bat` after `@ECHO OFF`